# Can I fly in Europe using an FAA Statement of Demonstrated Ability (SODA)?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical, easa-regulations, airline-pilot

I want to become a airline pilot but I have [Monocular vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocular_vision). I have no vision in my left eye but I have good vision in my right eye. I have read that I cannot become a pilot in Europe because of this condition.

So I just want to know if I can get a [Statement of Demonstrated Ability (SODA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_of_Demonstrated_Ability) equivalent in Europe and then become a airline pilot?

If that is not possible, then can I take an FAA medical class 1 with a [SODA](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/general/appeals/soda/), and then move back to Europe and fly in European airspace and fly internationally?

Comment: FAA regulations are only going to be valid within the USA and its territories.  You will have to consult with EASA or your local regulators about their standards for medical certification and waiver requirements.

Comment: But would it be easier for me if I have a valid faa medical class 1, and is it possible to get a soda in Europe.

Comment: That is something you would have to discuss with an AME if you were seeking flight training as a lawful resident in the United States

Answer (score 2):

> If that is not possible, then can I take an FAA medical class 1 with a
>   SODA, and then move back to Europe and fly in European airspace and
>   fly internationally?

Potentially, the FAA vision requirements, require you to have 20/20 in both eyes individually (corrected or uncorrected). [You can find a summary of the regulations here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/) to pass a standard medical. However the FAA does have a [special issuance for people with monocular vision which you can find more info on here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/exam_tech/et/31-34/mv/)

> An applicant will be considered monocular when there is only one eye
>   or when the best corrected distant visual acuity in the poorer eye is
>   no better than 20/200. An individual with one eye, or effective visual
>   acuity equivalent to monocular, may be considered for medical
>   certification, any class, through the special issuance section of part
>   67 ([14 CFR 67.401](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/67.401))

This would make you eligible for a class 1 medical which would allow you to train here in the US as well as get a full FAA commercial/ATP ticket which is valid in most of the world. Bottom line is that you can become an airline pilot (at least under FAA rules) and fly international, moving back to your home country may be an issue if they don't recognize an FAA license or the airline has its own medical regulations.

Comment: But it’s possible or am I wrong and does Germany recognize faa medical rules.

Comment: @NicolaiTrampedach they *should* if you hold an FAA pilot certificate and operate under FAA regulations. There are lots of questions here and elsewhere online about coming to the US for pilot training then heading back to Europe for a work.

Comment: Even if I’m monocular.

Comment: @NicolaiTrampedach You should speak to a german aviation official but my understanding is that you only must comply with the regulations of the license you are trying to fly with it does not matter *where* in the world  you are trying to do so as long as that location recognizes the privileges of the license.

Comment: Nice, it was because there was one who said that I could only get a private license.

Comment: Or can I only get a private license or can I get a commercial.

Comment: You should be able to obtain any FAA issued license as the regulation does not seem to stipulate a medical class cap.

Comment: So I could get a class 1 and become a commercial airline pilot with a faa license and fly for a European airline in European airspace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75264/discussion-between-dave-and-nicolai-trampedach). These are all good questions but are better suited for the chat. Some may turn into new questions here on the site as well.